# Am I Gone for Good?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

*I was there when you were young, and helped you make your art

I seemed much more vibrant then, but the drink took me apart*

*You were older but your hand gripped tight, showing me your fears

As we tried to answer questions, in front of all your peers*

*In older age you may fall ill, depending on your diet

Do not forget my remedy, though few still want to try it*

*Fair is how I judged you, and though you walked the line

You never once crossed over it, that margin very fine*

*Whether it is age or force that causes you to die

I will mark and remember the place in which you lie*

I have been around for some time, but am I recognizable to you anymore?
The answer is found in each stanza, but not all stanzas need be solved to provide it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are oft forgotten and supplanted by many newer things, but not quite gone yet...

> Chalk

*I was there when you were young, and helped you make your art*

*I seemed much more vibrant then, but the drink took me apart*

> Chalk coloring on sidewalks, etc...washes away easily with water.

*You were older but your hand gripped tight, showing me your fears*

*As we tried to answer questions, in front of all your peers*

> Getting called up to the blackboard in school to write down answers with chalk.

*In older age you may fall ill, depending on your diet*

*Do not forget my remedy, though few still want to try it*

> People would frequently consume chalk or chalk-like remedies for stomach ailments.

*Fair is how I judged you, and though you walked the line*

*You never once crossed over it, that margin very fine*

> Chalk is used to mark fair/foul in baseball (or other sports). (This one could be sketchy...)

*Whether it is age or force that causes you to die*

*I will mark and remember the place in which you lie*

> Chalk outlines are frequent markers of location/position of the deceased upon discovery by authorities, etc.

Comment: Well chalk up a correct answer for you. Correct on all accounts, so very nice job. I still like rand al'thor's answer, especially the gravestone part, but this one is all you.

Comment: @raisinghellyer Thanks. I'm thoroughly enjoying the creativity many of these questions bring out, even in the answers which don't align with the original intent (sometimes referred to as "wrong" answers). It definitely makes it worth reading more than just the "correct" answer.

Comment: Nice! If I'd taken a few more minutes to think about it, I might have got this one :-) +1

Comment: I would also note that some tailors (at least down here) use chalk to size you up for a suit, like the kind that you might wear when you are buried. Yet another usage that might work for the last stanza.

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> a PEN, or more generally WRITING?

*I was there when you were young, and helped you make your art

I seemed much more vibrant then, but the drink took me apart*

> Pens and pencils help children draw their art, often in vibrant colours. "Drink" refers to ink.

*You were older but your hand gripped tight, showing me your fears

As we tried to answer questions, in front of all your peers*

> Your hand grips your pen tightly when you're nervous in an exam.

*In older age you may fall ill, depending on your diet

Do not forget my remedy, though few still want to try it*

> Not sure about this bit. Maybe some quack remedy involving drinking ink?

*Fair is how I judged you, and though you walked the line

You never once crossed over it, that margin very fine*

> You often write on horizontal lines and between vertical margins.

*Whether it is age or force that causes you to die

I will mark and remember the place in which you lie*

> Writing on your gravestone.

Comment: 1 minute 8 seconds ... I hope I'm right!

Comment: Idk if it's right or not, but you didn't answer the question in his title.

Comment: @randal'thor You are very close, but just off by a smidgen. I like a lot of your answers, however, so if it takes too long, or is too difficult to get my intended answer, I might be inclined to accept this. Your speed was impressive alone.